# Fundamental Group Computation $\mathbb R^2 \setminus S^1$ .

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

I need to compute the fundamental group of $\mathbb R^2 \setminus  S^1$  .

First I notice this is a disconnected set, hence I will have to differentiate between two cases. If I choose the based point inside the bounded set ( the interior of $S^1$ ).

Clearly this is the trivial group since the open unit ball is convex.

On the other hand if I choose the based point $ x_{0}  \in \mathbb R^2 $ with $ |x_{0}| >1$, I guess this fundamental group could be isomorphic to $\mathbb Z$ since the loops I can have are pretty similar as the ones I can get if I have the punctured plane which fundamental group is $\mathbb Z$, but I can't find a satisfactory argument for this latest assertion. 
Am I right so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The circle $S^1$ is a deformation retraction of the complement of the unit ball by $H_t(x)={1\over \|x\|}tx +(1-t)x$ so its fundamental group is $Z$.

Comment: A retraction is not enough. You need a deformation retraction.